# A Riddle That Is 100% Pain

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Unseeded with marsh flower is he
> This youth approaching sanctity.
> Complexion bad, in lard rolls he.
>
> "Permit me", that was what I said
> In answer as I chopped his head.

The answer is a single English word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concealed word is:

> **ALLOW** (consider the title: 'all ow' = '100% pain'). Note that each of the first 3 lines contains references to multiple separate words spelled by adding a single letter to the front of 'ALLOW'...

*Unseeded with marsh flower is he*

> Unseeded = **(F)ALLOW**
>  Flower = **(M)ALLOW** (and 'with marsh' even yields **(MARSHM)ALLOW**!)

*This youth approaching sanctity.*

> Youth = **(C)ALLOW**
>  Sanctity = **(H)ALLOW**

*Complexion bad, in lard rolls he.*

> Complexion bad = **(S)ALLOW**
>  Lard = **(T)ALLOW**
>  In... rolls... = **(W)ALLOW**

*"Permit me", that was what I said*
*In answer as I chopped his head.*

> Additionally in this section, 'permit' is a synonym of **ALLOW**, and the reference to 'chopping his head' is a reflection of the wordplay used throughout this riddle: repeatedly removing and adding different 'heads' to the word. (And, who knows - perhaps this head-chopping happened at a **(G)ALLOW(S)**!)

Comment: Just to add: a verb for rolling in lard? (Or mud?)

Comment: And, of course, my congratulations on a job swiftly done!

Comment: @HughMeyers Ah yes, of course - added, thanks! :)